# JavaScript - How to calculate mileage expense total

Tags: javascript, logic, calculator

I'm currently developing an expenses form in which the user will input their mileage to a destination and their mileage from a destination.

There is a mileage band tariff, for example:
0-10 miles gets a single allowance of £20
11-20 miles gets an allowance of £30
21-30 miles gets an allowance of £40 etc etc

This rate will change on a yearly basis so I've created a table that has the rangeFrom and rangeTo fields as well as the allowance total so that they can be maintained.

What I'm struggling with is the best way to figure out how much a user should be paid for their journey. E.g. if they travel 24 miles to their destination then they should get an allowance of £20 but how do I calculate that.

Do I loop round a queryset from the table, creating a hidden form value for each mileage band and then try and figure out which band the entered value falls in to or is there an alternative method?

Comment: If "21-30 miles gets an allowance of £40", then why "24 miles to their destination then they should get an allowance of £20" ? Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple array as a lookup

```
var allowanceMapping = [
    {
       range: {low: 0, high: 10},
       allowance: 20
    }, {
       range: {low: 11, high: 20},
       allowance: 21
    }
];
```

Then, given a mileage, just loop thru the keys comparing on range.low and range.high....

```
var given;
for (vari = 0; i < allowanceMapping.length; i++) {
    var current = allowanceMapping[i];
    if (given >= current.range.low && given < current.range.high) return current.allowance;
}
```

Comment: But how would I store the table values in the array?

Comment: YOu would need to load the values from the database and create the appropriate data structures